# Taylor Series to the Power 1/z

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I am attempting to find the Taylor Series for $(\frac{\sin{z}}{z})^{\frac{1}{z^2}}$.  While I can plug this into Wolfram and use the output, I want to understand how to calculate the Taylor Series myself.  I can find the Taylor Series for $\frac{\sin{z}}{z}$ easily enough, but I cannot figure out for the power $\frac{1}{z^2}$ plays into things.

I just need to find the first few terms so that I can evaluate the limit, I do not need the nth term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write
$$
\Bigl(\frac{\sin z}{z}\Bigr)^{1/z^2}=\exp\Bigl(\frac{1}{z^2}\,\log\Bigl(\frac{\sin z}{z}\Bigr)\Bigr)
$$
I would first find a few terms of
$$
\frac{1}{z^2}\,\log\Bigl(\frac{\sin z}{z}\Bigr)=\frac{1}{z^2}\,\log\Bigl(1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}-\frac{z^6}{7!}+\dots\Bigr)
$$
using
$$
\log(1+w)=w-\frac{w^2}{2}+\frac{w^3}{3}-\frac{w^4}{4}+\dots
$$
and then use the Taylor expansion of $e^w$.

Answer (score 0):

1. The formula 4.3.71 on page 75 in the handbook [1] below reads that
   $$
   \ln\frac{\sin z}{z}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n2^{2n-1}B_{2n}}{n(2n)!}z^{2n}, \quad |z|<\pi.
   $$
   Hence, we have
   $$
   \frac1{z^2}\ln\frac{\sin z}{z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}2^{2n+1}B_{2n+2}}{(n+1)(2n+2)!}z^{2n}, \quad |z|<\pi.
   $$

[1] M. Abramowitz and I. A. Stegun (Eds), *Handbook of Mathematical Functions with Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables*, National Bureau of Standards, Applied Mathematics Series **55**, 10th printing, Dover Publications, New York and Washington, 1972.

2. Let
   \begin{equation*}
   D(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty d_kx^k
   \end{equation*}
   be a power series expansion. Then the function $E(x)=e^{D(x)}$ has the power series expansion
   \begin{equation*}
   E(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty e_kx^k,
   \end{equation*}
   where the coefficients $e_k$ for $k\in\{0\}\cup\mathbb{N}$ satisfy
   \begin{align}
   e_0&=e^{d_0},\\
   e_k&=\frac1k\sum_{\ell=1}^k\ell d_\ell e_{k-\ell}
   =\frac1k\sum_{\ell=0}^{k-1}(k-\ell)d_{k-\ell}e_{\ell},\quad k\in\mathbb{N},\\
   e_n&=e^{d_0}\left(d_n+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{\substack{\sum_{i=0}^jm_i=n,\\ m_i\ge1, 0\le i\le j}} \prod_{i=0}^j\frac{m_id_{m_i}}{n-\sum_{q=0}^{i-1}m_q}\right), \quad n\in\mathbb{N},
   \end{align}
   and
   \begin{equation}\label{alpha-k-power-eq}
   e_k= e^{d_0}\sum_{j=1}^k\frac1{j!} \sum_{\substack{\sum_{\ell=1}^ji_\ell=k,\\ i_\ell\ge1,1\le\ell\le j}} \prod_{\ell=1}^jd_{i_\ell}, \quad k\in\mathbb{N}.
   \end{equation}
   These conclusions can be found in the paper [2] below.

[2] Feng Qi, Xiao-Ting Shi, and Fang-Fang Liu, *Expansions of the exponential and the logarithm of power series and applications*, Arabian Journal of Mathematics **6** (2017), no. 2, 95--108; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s40065-017-0166-4.

3. Consequently, we finally can obtain
   \begin{align}
   \biggl(\frac{\sin z}{z}\biggr)^{1/z^2}
   &=\exp\Biggl(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}2^{2n+1}B_{2n+2}}{(n+1)(2n+2)!}z^{2n}\Biggr)\\
   &=\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]{e}}-\frac{z^2}{180 \sqrt[6]{e}}-\frac{17 z^4}{50400 \sqrt[6]{e}}-\frac{6007 z^6}{244944000 \sqrt[6]{e}}-\frac{26263141 z^8}{13579695360000 \sqrt[6]{e}}-\dotsm
   \end{align}